# Bibliography not generating at Springer cloud

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to submit a `manuscript` at `Springer` but on `building PDF` on springer I can see `references` are not getting generated. When I compile the same document on `Overleaf` it works fine.

**Template Tex code**

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% file template.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% This is a general template file for the LaTeX package SVJour3
% for Springer journals.          Springer Heidelberg 2010/09/16
%
% Copy it to a new file with a new name and use it as the basis
% for your article. Delete % signs as needed.
%
% This template includes a few options for different layouts and
% content for various journals. Please consult a previous issue of
% your journal as needed.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% First comes an example EPS file -- just ignore it and
% proceed on the \documentclass line
% your LaTeX will extract the file if required
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
%%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
%%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
%%EndComments
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%
\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PAPER Content %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
%
%
%
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% BibTeX users please use one of
%\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}   % name your BibTeX data base

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

**Reference Section**

[image]

**File uploaded to Springer cloud**

[image]

I couldn't figure out the problem, It's very frustrating any help would be appreciated Thank you.

Comment: I don't know about Springer, but often you need to include the `.bbl` file or a copy of the `.bbl` data in the `.tex` file if you upload your document for submission to a publisher. Did you do that? Did you have a look at Springer's author guidelines for submitting papers with bibliographies?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://www.overleaf.com/help/219-the-journal-says-dont-use-bibtex-paste-the-contents-of-the-bbl-file-into-the-tex-file-how-do-i-do-this-on-overleaf. As I mentioned above many publishers don't want to run BibTeX on your submission and will only run LaTeX. In that case you must include the `.bbl` into the `.tex` file or supply it alongside the `.tex` file. But as I said above, I have never submitted anything to Springer and don't know about the upload, submission and compilation process, so you need to check the guidelines and help that they offer you.

Comment: @moewe Hello, I have compiled template locally in `Kile` and uploaded `template.bbl` as  `Electronic Supplementary material` as per your suggestion, but problem still persists

Comment: Sorry, that is all I can say. I don't know how their system works. There should be documentation on that when you upload stuff. If not you will have to contact Springer directly.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Copy the .bbl data into the .tex file, instead of the `\bibliography{references}` macro.  In the example below, I've commented out the references line, and included one bibitem from my own paper, just to show how it looks. You'll want to delete that and copy your own material in.

```
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      
%\bibliography{references}   
\begin{thebibliography}{96}
\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{{#1}}
\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL }
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax
  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{DOI~\discretionary{}{}{}#1}\else
  \providecommand{\doi}{DOI~\discretionary{}{}{}\begingroup
  \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi
\providecommand{\eprint}[2][]{\url{#2}}

\bibitem[{Aberdein and Dove(2013)}]{Aberdein2013}
Aberdein A, Dove IJ (2013) Introduction. In: Aberdein A, Dove IJ (eds) The
  Argument of Mathematics, Springer Netherlands, Dordrecht, pp 1--8,
  \urlprefix\url{https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-007-6534-4_1}


...
\end{thebibliography}
```